# Show the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^2+x^4}{n^4+x^2}$ pointwise converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification

Show that for all $x\in\mathbb R$ the series$$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^2+x^4}{n^4+x^2}$$ converges to a continuous function.

*My attempt:* First restrict to $[-r,r]\subset\mathbb R$ and use Weierstrass' M-test (see page 12 of [this](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131bh.1.03s/week3.pdf) note by T. Tao)

Take the sup-norm:
$$||f_n||_{\infty}=\sup\left\{\frac{n^2+x^4}{n^4+x^2}:|x|\leq r\right\}=\frac{n^2+r^4}{n^4+r^2}$$
$F|_{[-r,r]}(x)$ converges uniformly to a continuous function if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}||f_n||_{\infty}$ converges, which is true by comparison:
$$\frac{n^2+r^4}{n^4+r^2}\leq \frac{n^2+r^4}{n^4}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{r^4}{n^4}$$

And the fact that $F(x)$ converges uniformly on any interval $[-r,r]$ means that $F(x)$ must be point-wise convergent on the whole real line. (Is this correct?)

Please help me verify or improve this proof, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The proof looks fine to me.

The last fact you mentioned is correct. Actually, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we can choose $r>|x|$. Since $F$ converges uniformly on $[-r, r]$, and every term in the sum is continuous, $F$ is continuous on $[-r, r]$, thus is continuous at $x$.